# Google Cloud Text-to-Speech Audio to Browser

Tags: python, audio, text-to-speech

I use google-cloud text-to-speech API using python3 on linux.

The mp3 plays with os.startfile(), which opens a player.

Instead sending mp3 file &  using mp3 player, I need to play audio through the browser.

**I have tried:**

1. “Python Media Player” —-defunct.
2. “20.1. webbrowser”— defunct.
3. “Rhythmbox” —simply another player.
4. “Pygame” — overkill.
5. "Pyglet" - overkill
6. SoX and pySoX, —Don’t appear to play the files they manipulate.
7. I read part of Schwoebel’s  “An Introduction to Voice Computing in Python.”
8. "gl_talk" — Wasn't able to implement; very little documentation.

I need advice on how to mimic what google has done in the browser as in the link here:

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gTTS module to do text-to-speech in Python. And then you can use another module to play the sound using Python as well.

**First install the following modules...**

```
pip install gTTS

pip install playsound
```

**Then you can do this...**

```
from gtts import gTTS
import playsound
tts = gTTS('hello')
tts.save('hello.mp3')

playsound.playsound('hello.mp3')
```

**This code should give you the same results as google in browser, because gtts uses the same API. If you have any problems you can comment and I will definitely reply :)**

Comment: Umm Just asking did the code work for you?

Comment: I am glad that my answer helped you. :)